# Any ideas on why my syntax is wrong for np.identity?

Tags: python, numpy

I keep getting a syntax error from this one line:

```
lambda = np.ones((D,D)) - np.identity(D))
```

where

```
classpriors = np.array([0.65,0.35])
L = len(classpriors)
D = np.array(range(L))
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the lambda line -- any ideas?

Comment: `lambda` is a build-in function don't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

[`lambda` is a reserved keyword in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda); you can't use it as an identifier. (You can find the [full list of keywords here.](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords))

`Lambda` is fine, `lambda_` is fine, `lamb` is fine, even `λ` is fine (though a bit of a chore to type):

```
>>> λ = 5
>>> λ * 2
10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you maybe try to archive is this, having the matrices constructed by `D.size`?

```
import numpy as np
classpriors = np.array([0.65,0.35])
L = len(classpriors)
D = np.array(range(L))

lam = np.ones((D.size,D.size)) - np.identity(D.size)
```

Anyways, creating arrays with sizes given as arrays like in your version, does not make sense.